# Looking for geocoding data for New York State

Tags: geocoding

I have tried the following local data sets:

- TIGER 2010
- TIGER 2006
- www.datasciencetoolkit.org
- http://www.gisgraphy.com

They are all very inaccurate for data in New York State. I need the data to work at the street/house level similar to google maps.

I have searched all over the place and it does not seem this type of data exists.

Any recommendations?

Comment: The [NYS streets dataset](http://gis.ny.gov/gisdata/inventories/details.cfm?DSID=932) from the NYS Office of Cyber Security is better than TIGER files in some areas, but is similar to TIGER in most rural areas. That same NYS GIS clearinghouse site has many county agencies, some which release parcel data, which may be more accurate than street centerline data (especially in rural areas), but is likely more dated. Also the same [NYS agency](http://www.dhses.ny.gov/ocs/streets/#sam) is making a online geocoding api in the works I believe. Something to keep in mind for the future.

Comment: Essentially anywhere rural, without parcel data, will be innaccurate by many standards. Also places of rapid development won't have up-to-date data (missing street names essentially).